# Android:Make characters bold in xml

Tags: android, xml

I write this line in the strings.xml:

```
<string name="Help">This<b>Caaaaaa</b> on the spot.</string>
```

But the characters between the `<b>` tag don't become bold. What am I doing incorrectly?
PS:I just wanna make some part in the string (like "Caaaaa" above) bold.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you set the text of some widget to this string use the following code:

In strings.xml use this to add ur string:

```
<string name="Help">
    <![CDATA[
    This <b>Caaaaaa</b> on the spot.
    ]]>
    </string>
```

In your activity

```
yourWidget.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.Help)));
```

Comment: huh? @ZhaoRocky what do you mean it doesn't work? It's been used for ever!

Comment: Thanks so much and I'm sorry for my previous comment.:-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that in string.xml file.

but you can set **textStyle="bold"** where you are using it.

like-

```
<TextView android:textSize="18dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:text="@string/Help" 
    android:id="@+id/header">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Yeah,but using this method I have to add some other operations dealing with the characters-"Caaaaaa",including adding one or more TextView.:(

Answer (score 1):

Tags in XML, for example `<string>` and `<b>` have no intrinsic meaning. The tag `<b>` only means "bold" if the software processing the XML thinks that it means bold and treats it as meaning bold. You haven't said what software is processing the XML.

If this were HTML rather than XML, it would be a different matter.

Comment: Thanks.I write it in the 'strings.xml' file and get the string by 'String a = res.getString(R.string.Help)'.Then I set it to a 'TextView':'tv.setText(a)';So How can I get the bold string?

Comment: It seems you were asking the question in relation to an application where your XML file is being used as an android "string resource file". Your question didn't make this clear. XML tags have no meaning except in relation to a specific vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextStyle). You can set the text style in the layout XML file.