# How to change style of specific rows in android ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

I have a listview in my app, which is declared in XML, then the content is passed to it in code based on a string array which I have declared in XML. I'm new to android programming, but I was wondering how I could make the text in certain listview elements **bold** and darken the listview background behind it.

[image: Here's the sort of thing I want to do]

I have my set names as an array in my strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="setsArray">
    <item>set1</item>
    <item>set2</item>
    <item>set3</item>
    <item>set4</item>
    <item>set5</item>
    <item>set6</item>
</string-array>
```

I have my listview declared in the activity's layout.xml

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

And in the code of the activity I have this:

```
final ListView setList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    setList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.setsArray)));

    setList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            int itemPosition = position;

            String itemValue = (String) setList.getItemAtPosition(itemPosition);

            if (!itemValue.equals("SPANISH")){

                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SetViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", itemValue);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }

    });
```

Note that this code takes the name of the set that was clicked on, and passes it onto the next activity with the intent so it knows what to display. If possible I need to keep this intact or replace it with another system which sends something which I can use to distinguish the sets in the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

because you don't use a custom adapter (I guess), try this please:

```
 <string-array name="setsArray">
 <item>set1</item>
 <item>set2</item>
 <item>set3</item>
 <item>set4</item>
 <item>  <![CDATA[ <b>set5</b>  ]]>  </item>
 <item>set6</item>
 </string-array>
```

I hope android using Html.fromHtml() by default :)

[Android:Make characters bold in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816728/androidmake-characters-bold-in-xml)

Comment: It doesn't work by default. How would I go about implementing yourWidget.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.Help))); in my ListView as the ArrayAdapter doesn't want to take an HTML input?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to implement custom `ListAdapter`. In [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method you'll be able to change style of item based on index.

As a side note, I don't see a reason why you wouldn't use `RecyclerView`. It's a more flexible and up to date choice for creating lists.

With RecyclerView it could be done like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
        if(position == 5) holder.mTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);    
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but how would I go about making a simple custom ListAdapter? I've done some googling but everything seems beyond me.

Comment: @mxbi I'd suggest to take a look at this: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

Please watch [The World of ListView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQyCkwAGoVChMI4KaHq6KhxwIVkiuICh0ggABf&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70&ei=aQrKVaDOJJLXoASggIL4BQ&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=l4jP1V9SOBoYn-DSttJdYA). It explains the important aspects of ListViews and how to make an adapters for your ListView. Pay particular attention to the part about using `getItemViewType()` and [`getViewTypeCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()).